# EnableFilter is not available on IStatelessSession but ISession ( NHibernate 2.0 )

Tags: nhibernate

IStatelessSession does not have some of the functions like EnableFilter. Is there an alternative to this method on stateless session ?

Does IStatelessSession support lazy loading ?
Is there a way to convert ( or cast ) ISession to IStatelessSession ?

we are upgrading our code base with NH 2.0 and there are lots of code in DAL layer thats exchanging ISession at present. We want to use IStateless session for most of the

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IStateless does not support Lazy Loading, nor filters, dirty checking, caching, etc.

It's a lower-level abstraction, not something you can just replace ISession with.